# Memory leak with SWIG and Java

Tags: java, c++, memory-leaks, containers, swig

I’m calling a C++ program from Java using SWIG. The SWIG wrapper file defines a ‘stringmatrix’ structure as follows:

```
%include "std_string.i"
%include "std_vector.i"
%{
#include <vector>
%}
namespace std
{
%template(stringvector) std::vector<std::string>; 
%template(stringmatrix) std::vector< std::vector<std::string> >; 
}
```

In Java, I set up a stringmatrix object with the following:

```
public static stringmatrix BuildMatrix( int n )
    {
        stringmatrix s_data = new stringmatrix( n );
        for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            stringvector s1 = new stringvector ( 3 );
            s1.set ( 0, "A");
            s1.set ( 1, "B");
            s1.set ( 1, "C");            
            s_data.set ( s, s1 );
        }
        return s_data;
    }
```

And a function to release memory:

```
public static void ReleaseStringMatrix ( stringmatrix s )
{
        for ( int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++ )
            s.get(i).delete();
        s.delete();
}
```

Then call it using

```
stringmatrix s_test;
s_test = BuildSecurityMaster( 10000 );
ReleaseStringMatrix (s_test);
```

This appears to load and free memory fine – except when running Java in a container, where the memory is not freed and native memory grows until the process crashes. This happens even when simply allocating and releasing memory, as shown here.

Has anybody seen anything similar? Using javac 1.8.0.291, gcc 7.4, swig 3.0.8. If we just work with StringVector types, everything is allocated and released as expected.